# Laravel issue in room booking

Tags: laravel

Hi all I have some issue with my code ..
The idea is that I have multi room's which I retrieve from database  every room have multi booking date my idea is to show when open room page all page if the room have current reservation mark it red  or future reservation marked blue  I can't know how to make this happen  my room.blade is:

```
@section('content')
<div class="row  text-right  ">

    @foreach ($room_typ as $a )


            <div class="col-12 col-lg-2">
                <div class="card  radius-15">
                    <div class="card-body text-center  radius-15">
                        <h4 title="{{ $a->r_det }}" class="mb-0 font-weight-bold mt-0 text-white">{{ $a->r_name }}
                        </h4>-<h6>{{ $a->f_name }}</h6>
                        <span class="mt-1 mb-1 acupp"></span>
                        <a href="{{ route('add_room_res', $a->r_name) }}"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href=""><i class="fadeIn animated bx bx-trash-alt mr-md-3"></i></a>
                        <a href=""><i class="bx bx-info-square mr-md-3"></i></a>
                        {{ $rr }} // should show the count for reservation with room number
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

@endsection

the controller is :

```
   public function allrom()
{
    $room_typ = addroom::all();
    foreach ($room_typ as $dd) {
        $rom = $dd->r_name;
        $rr = res_c::where('rno', '=', $rom)->get();
    }
    echo view('room', compact('room_typ',  'rr'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please change the checkin and checkout fields with the one in your database let me know if it work

```
 @section('content')
    <div class="row  text-right  ">
        @foreach ($room_typ as $a )
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="card  radius-15" style="{{ date("Y-m-d") >= date("Y-m-d",strtotime($a->r_date_checkin)) &&  date("Y-m-d") < date("Y-m-d",strtotime($a->r_date_checkout)) ? "background-color:red" : ( date("Y-m-d") > date("Y-m-d",strtotime($a->r_date_checkin) ) ) ? "background-color:blue" : ""  }}">
                        <div class="card-body text-center  radius-15">
                            <h4 title="{{ $a->r_det }}" class="mb-0 font-weight-bold mt-0 text-white">{{ $a->r_name }}
                            </h4>-<h6>{{ $a->f_name }}</h6>
                            <span class="mt-1 mb-1 acupp"></span>
                            <a href="{{ route('add_room_res', $a->r_name) }}"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i></a>
                            <a href=""><i class="fadeIn animated bx bx-trash-alt mr-md-3"></i></a>
                            <a href=""><i class="bx bx-info-square mr-md-3"></i></a>
                            {{ $rr }} // should show the count for reservation with room number
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```